# c++ return structures and vectors optimally

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am reading a lot of different things on C++ optimization and I am getting quite mixed up. I would appreciate some help. Basically, I want to clear up what needs to be a pointer or not when I am passing vectors and structures as parameters or returning vectors and structures.

Say I have a Structure that contains 2 elements: an int and then a vector of integers. I will be creating this structure locally in a function, and then returning it. This function will be called multiple times and generate a new structure every time. I would like to keep the last structure created in a class member (lastStruct_ for example). So before returning the struct I could update lastStruct_ in some way.

Now, what would be the best way to do this, knowing that the vector in the structure can be quite large (would need to avoid copies). Does the vector in the struct need to be a pointer ? If I want to share lastStruct_ to other classes by creating a get_lastStruct() method, should I return a reference to lastStruct_, a pointer, or not care about that ? Should lastStruct_ be a shared pointer ?

This is quite confusing to me because apparently C++ knows how to avoid copying, but I also see a lot of people recommending the use of pointers while others say a pointer to a vector makes no sense at all.

```
struct MyStruct {
    std::vector<int> pixels;
    int foo;
}

class MyClass {
    MyStruct lastStruct_;
public:
    MyStruct create_struct();
    MyStruct getLastStruct();
}

MyClass::create_struct()
{
    MyStruct s = {std::vector<int>(100, 1), 1234};
    lastStruct_ = s;
    return s;
}

MyClass::getLastStruct()
{
    return lastStruct_;
}
```

Comment: So it depends on the version of C++, anything newer than C++11 should do RVO. Newer versions may even guarantee copy elision.

Comment: "a lot of people recommending the use of pointers". They just didn't get the memo yet.

Comment: So what I understand is the vector in the struct should be a plain vector. The struct should be returned normally (return the_struct). Attribute lastStruct_ should be a plain struct. I would update with normal asssignaton lastStruct_ = the_struct. Finally when I share this lastStruct_ through a getter I would simply return lastStruct_ ? Is it really that simple (is C++>11 really that good) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only copy you're trying to remove is the one that happen when you return it from your factory function, I'd say containing the vector directly will be faster *all the time*.

Why? Two things. Return Value Optimisation (RVO/NRVO) will remove any need for temporaries when returning. This is enough for almost all cases.

When return value optimisation don't apply, move semantics will. returning a named variable (eg: `return my_struct;`) will do implicit move in the case NRVO won't apply.

So why is it always faster than a shared pointer? Because when copying the shared pointer, you must dereference the control block to increase the owner count. And since it's an atomic operation, the incrementation is not free.

Also, using a shared pointer brings shared ownership and non-locality. If you were to use a shared pointer, use a pointer to const data to bring back value semantics.

---

Now that you added the code, it's much clearer what you're trying to do.

There's no way around the copy here. If you measure performance degradation, then containing a `std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<int>>` might be the solution, since you'll keep value semantic but avoid vector copy.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I believe I am following you for the vector in the struct. The struct is returned and then becomes out of scope so c++ knows how to optimize this. But for the class attribute lastStruct that contains the last struct created, this one will always be in scope. So when I try to share this variable to other classes so they can access the last available data, if I simply `return lastStruct;` then will c++ need to copy it ? A move would "steal" the data I feel like.

Comment: @XDD If you want a private data member and a getter for it, then a reference to const will remove the need for copy, because `return nonLocal` will always copy in that case. Unless you do `std::move(nonLocal)`, but I'd avoid that.

Comment: Ok I see. I think this answers the majority of my questions. C++ is intelligent enough to avoid copies when returning an object that will become out of scope. Then a reference to const will make sharing the private member (lastStruct) quick and easy. The last concern would be about the update of the private member lastStruct. In the factory where local struct are created and then returned, I would like to update lastStruct. Is there a way to avoid a copy there ?

Comment: If you do `my_member = make_struct()` then there is no copy, since the object returned by `make_struct()` is a temporary. It's a move in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure I was explaining correctly. It should be much clearer with the example code I added in the question. From what I understood, there will be no copies in the example code, except for `lastStruct_ = s;`. Is there a way to avoid this one ?

Comment: @XDD in that case `my_member = std::move(non_temporary)` will force a move. `std::move` will cast a named object to a temporary one.

Comment: Now I think I'm lost again haha ! By doing `lastStruct_ = std::move(s);` I would avoid the cost of copying in my member. But now I would not be able to `return s;` at the end, right ? So I would have to return lastStruct_, but since it is staying in scope C++ won't be able to delete it or move it, hence C++ would make a copy ?

Comment: @XDD Oh, I just saw the example with the code, and I know what you mean by last struct. No, you fundamentally want a copy there, so C++ can't help you remove it. If you really want to avoid the copy of the whole vector, I'd try `std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<int>>` to keep value semantic. And even that, I'd hide the shared pointer as a private member.